# SQL Server BULK INSERT errored out and did not release Sch-M lock, table is unaccessible

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

TLDR: I think SQL Server did not release a Sch-M lock and I can't release it or find the transaction holding the lock

I was trying to build a copy of another table and run some benchmarking on the data updates from disk, and when running a BULK INSERT on the empty table it errored out because I had used the wrong file name. I was running the script by selecting a large portion of text from a notepad in SQL Server Management Studio and hitting the Execute button. Now, no queries regarding the table whatsoever can execute, including things like OBJECT_ID or schema information in SQL Server Management Studio when manually refreshed. The queries just hang, and in the latter case SSMS gives an error about a lock not being relinquished within a timeout.

I have taken a few debugging steps so far.

I took a look at the `sys.dm_tran_locks` table filtered on the DB's resource ID. There, I can see a number of shared locks on the DB itself and some exclusive key locks, and exactly 1 lock on an object, a Sch-M lock. When I try and get the object name from the resource ID on the `sys.dm_tran_locks` table, the query hangs just like OBJECT_ID() does (and does not for other table names/IDs). The lock cites session ID 54.

I have also taken a look at the `sys.dm_exec_requests` table to try and find more information about SPID 54, but there are no rows with that session id. In fact, the only processes there are ones owned by `sa` and the single query checking the `sys.dm_exec_requests` table, owned by myself.

From this, if I understand everything correctly, it seems like somehow the BULK INSERT statement somehow failed to release the Sch-M lock that it takes.

So here are my questions: Why is there still a Sch-M lock on the table if the process that owns it seems to no longer exist? Is there some way to recover access to the table without restarting the SQL Server process? Would SQL code in the script after the BULK INSERT have run, but just on an empty table?

I am using SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: Perhaps you have an open transaction in an SSMS window. Check with `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;` or `DBCC OPENTRAN;`.

Comment: @DanGuzman `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` returns 0 but `DBCC OPENTRAN` lists a transaction with SPID 54 as the oldest active transaction. Is there a way to roll back/terminate that transaction using data from that printout?

Comment: Execute `kill 54;` to rollback the transaction and kill the session.